# Elements position relative to text input

Tags: html, css

I have the following challenge. When an user is typing somehting in an input field, I want to show a reset button with a position center right of the input.

I am not able to change the html structure of the label, input, button and the error message. And I dont want to use browsers support. Does somebody has a creative idea how to do this? Thanks in advance.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopping-cart-coupon">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="coupon">Coupon</label>
    <input name="coupon" type="text" id="coupon">
    <a id="" style="" class="btn" href=''>Activate</a>
    <span style="display:block;color:red;">Error message</span>
    <a class="reset">x</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I already know that I can't fix this with `position: absolute` because you have to handle with the label and, possible, the error message. So to be honest nothing, because I am out of my solutions. And the `after`en `before` pseudo-elements are not working for an input.

Comment: @NiZa I've added an answer with a generic strategy, but I can detail it if you explain better where you want your reset button to be (*center right* of what? inside/outside?).

Comment: @AlinPurcaru The align should be vertical and right to the input field.

Comment: @NiZa Just to make sure I understand it correctly. Can you change your HTML markup? Or do you need to do it only with CSS?

Comment: The html order needs to be `label` and then `input`. Without any html in between.

Comment: @NiZa Then why don't you put your reset immediately after the `input` and then shift it with positioning?

Comment: Let's do it like this: You take some more time and explain in the question *exactly* what you can and can't do, and then I'll tell you if it is possible or not. Deal?

Comment: I think your comment here before helped me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
}

.reset {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopping-cart-coupon">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="coupon">Coupon</label>
    <input name="coupon" type="text" id="coupon">
    <a class="reset">x</a>
    <a id="" style="" class="btn" href=''>Activate</a>
    <span style="display:block;color:red;">Error message</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

**Outline**

Wrap anything that you want to stay as it is now with an `<div style="display: inline-block;position:relative;">`. This creates a positioning context in which you can position anything afterwards. Then position your reset button with `position: absolute` and the offsets you need, inside and relative to the wrapper you created.

Here's a try at it, but I'm uncertain that I understood your scenario.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.reset {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopping-cart-coupon">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="coupon">Coupon</label>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input name="coupon" type="text" id="coupon">
      <a class="reset">x</a>
    </div>
    <a id="" style="" class="btn" href=''>Activate</a>
    <span style="display:block;color:red;">Error message</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See my last comment of the question. The html order needs to be label and then input. Without any html in between.